# Header is not working

Tags: php, url, header

My header is not working.

```
<?php 
$name = mysql_prep($_POST['name']);
$pastor = mysql_prep($_POST['pastor']);
$head = mysql_prep($_POST['head']);
$schedule = mysql_prep($_POST['schedule']);
$venue = mysql_prep($_POST['venue']);
$id = mysql_prep($_GET['ministryid']);
$errors = array();

    $required_field = array('name', 'pastor', 'address', 'schedule', 'venue');
    foreach ($required_field as $fieldname) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])) {
        $errors[] = $fieldname;
        echo "Sorry, you missed to complete {$fieldname} <br />";
        }
    else {
        $query = "UPDATE ministry SET
        name = '{$name}', 
        pastor = '{$pastor}', 
        head = '{$head}', 
        schedule = '{$schedule}',
        venue = '{$venue}'
        WHERE id = {$id}";

        mysql_query($query);
        if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {                 
            header('location: editministry.php?');
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "Updating Failed on {$s_ministry['name']} <b />".mysql_error();
            exit;
        }
    }
    }

require_once("include/footer.php");
```

Every time I have successful update, the link change its address.

For example, when I'm updating `id = 3`, the address will change to editministry.php?ministryid=3.

Comment: try removing "?" from header location, header("Location: editministry.php");

Comment: does if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1) condition is satisfying?, try echo mysql_affected_rows(); and check what values your getting or you can check if(mysql_affected_rows() > 0) condition

Comment: The fact that there isnt a redirect URL within the else statment suggest that the condition is met, else there would be an error message displayed. Can you try linkin it to another page? such as your index.php? And see if that redirect works.

Answer (score 0):

You dont send anything along your URL, thats why your header won't work. Check for yourself.

```
if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {                 
            header('location: editministry.php?');
            exit;
```

Your link will become effectivly baseUrl/editministry.php?.It searches than for a variable, which is not defined. I am not sure how you actually can pass on a variable that you didnt define in a link, yet it sends you there. Don't know. But if you just tell it to the hard link without the questionmark, it should go to that page. For me it works at least within my code. For you it would be:

```
if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1) {                 
            header('location: editministry.php' );
            exit;
```

In my code it looks like this:

```
header( "Location: http://" . strip_tags( $_SERVER ['HTTP_HOST'] ) . "/newHolo/index.php" );
```